# Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 gives black screen and x cursor on startup

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, xorg, chroot, chromeos

I have a Dell 11 chromebook on which I downloaded crouton, and through that, ubuntu 12.04. 12.04 was working perfectly well until I got a message from the update manager asking me to update to trusty 14.04, so I did.

I clicked yes and forward on whatever I needed to. When it was finished I shut down my chromebook and did something else. On my return I boot up crouton and type sudo startunity. It says stuff and eventually brings me to a black screen with an x cursor that has a white border.

A password prompt comes up and I type in what my password was for ubuntu 12.04. Nothing happens, so I hit the keys Ctrl+Alt+-> and try to log on there, but it also doesn't work. I am so confused, can anyone help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

If either ChromeOS or the Chroot has been updated, you must go to the chrome shell and type the command:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n <chroot_name> -u
```

Your "chroot_name" should be "precise" if defaults were used during the install. If you would like the name to match the current Ubuntu release to relieve confusion, you may use the following to rename the chroot:

```
sudo edit-chroot <old_chroot_name> -m <new_chroot_name>
```

Or in your case:

```
sudo edit-chroot trusty -m precise
```